# Why do back-ticks in styled-components have the ability to access props.theme?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a question about how backticks work in styled-components.

Let's say I define and pass down a theme using their `ThemeProvider`:

```
const theme = {
  primary: '#df0000',
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I can define a "styled Div" that accesses `props.theme.primary` in App.js like so:

```
const App = props => {
  const Div = styled.div`
    background-color: ${props => props.theme.primary};
  `

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(props)}
      <h1>Welcome to React Parcel Micro App!</h1>
      <p>Hard to get more minimal than this React app.</p>
      <Div>lol</Div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

That's great, except `props.theme` is only accessible to Div because it was inside the `${}` which was inside the backticks. `console.log(props.theme)` says `undefined`. However, if I use `export default withTheme(App)` I do see that console.log prints the theme.

How do backticks in styled-components allow access to `props.theme`?

Answer (score 5):

All styled components have access to the theme internally from the context if it exists.

It doesn't matter where you define the component, it will still be able to access the context when it is rendered.

Here's a link to the [the current implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/styled-components/styled-components/2aa15b3da64d3e799e0fde6634300f9893a4c1c3/packages/styled-components/src/models/StyledComponent.js) where you can see it accessing the context.

```js
  // Snippet from StyledComponent.js

  const theme = determineTheme(props, useContext(ThemeContext), defaultProps);
```

But your question is specifically about how the back-ticks work, so here's the rest of the answer:

styled components use `template literals`, specifically the `tagged templates` feature.

Here's an extract [from MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

> #### Tagged templates
>
> A more advanced form of template literals are tagged templates.
>
> Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function. The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string values. The remaining arguments are related to the expressions.
>
> The tag function can then perform whatever operations on these arguments you wish, and return the manipulated string. (Alternatively, it can return something completely different, as described in one of the following examples.)

So in your example:

```js
const Div = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.primary};
`

// is conceptually like calling the styled.div function with the following arguments: 

(
  ['background-color: ', ';'], // array of strings, 
  props => props.theme.primary // each expression is passed in as a new param
)
```

Once the tagged template is split into strings and functions. It gets wrapped up into the styled component. At render time all the functions are called with the props of the styled component (and the theme from the context).

Each function called with props returns a string. Then we can stitch the array of strings and the return values of the functions together and we end up with the final styles.

```
 ['background-color: ', ';'],
  props => props.theme.primary // returns a string e.g. "green"
```

Now we have all the strings they can be stitched back together as styles:

```
  'background-color: ' + 'green' + ';'
```

There are optimizations done under the hood but this is the basics of how styled components back-ticks work.

One of the creators has a [great blog post](https://mxstbr.blog/2016/11/styled-components-magic-explained/) with more info about styled-components tagged templates.